# Geocoder class gives wrong coordinates and won't parse coordinates to get street address. Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I typed in the code from http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/ and I keep getting the coordinates for the Xamarin office in San Francisco as my current location when I run the app.

I have installed the Google Maps apk on my Nexus 4 (KitKat) API 19 emulator and Google Maps displays my current location as San Francisco.

The app won't parse the coordinates to get the street address.

I have tried adding Google Play Services through Xamarin, but when debugging it freezes and I have to kill it.

Comment: What do you mean by "The app won't parse the coordinates to get the street address."?  Can you give a specific example, including the code?

Comment: `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
   IList<Address> addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

   Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
   if (address != null)
   {
    StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
    {
     deviceAddress.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i))
      .AppendLine(",");
    }
    _addressText.Text = deviceAddress.ToString();
   }
   else
   {
    _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address.";
   }`

Comment: the coordinates are supposed to be parsed and returned as a string which is the address

Comment: can you please post your code in the question so its easier to read and don't go unnoticed by people who can answer it possibly?

Comment: That being said, you mentioned "the coordinates are supposed to be parsed and returned as a string which is the address". Show the implementation you are using to fetch and send the address string (or error) that you got as a result to respective activity.

Comment: @KayAnn I realised the code was working perfectly, the emulator was working with simulated coordinates, simulated to San Francisco. `LocationManager` was returning null coordinated all the time, so my set `exception` was always thrown. I played around with my virtualbox network settings, I had to change my adapter settings to a bridged networked instead of virtualised network. It made my emulator slower, but it works.

Comment: Oh yeah you have to tweak network a little to test GPS functionalities in emulator. Well glad you found a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Xamarin Android Player, the GPS coordinates are simulated.

You need to update the location you want. To do this click on Settings then the GPS tab.

Your app will see the new coordinates and should return the correct address.

Comment: Thanks that helped, the emulator coordinates were simulated. I played around with my virtualbox networked settings and it worked.